# Find implementation of ReactiveCrudRepository

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-data-mongodb, reactive

`org.springframework.data.repository.reactive.ReactiveCrudRepository` is annotated with `@NoRepositoryBean`. I need to implement the methods in `ReactiveCrudRepository` for a specific repository because I need to do mapping from one entity to another - as there is some problems with the spring-configurationusing using springs converters.

Where can the implementation of `ReactiveCrudRepository` be found?

Edit:
E.g the **save** method sets an Id on the object. This is not stated in the method documentation. Which only states: "Saves a given entity. Use the returned instance for further operations as the save operation might have changed the entity instance completely."

So if you dont overwrite the object with the return object - there is a side-effect that your object is updated with an Id. Which makes sense, but its not documented, and so seeing the implementation would help.

Comment: Which feels like you are solving this at the wrong level. Can you show what the conversion is you need to do and why it doesn't work currently? Reimplementing the whole repository doesn't sound like the proper solution.

Answer (score 1):

A little late but the code you are looking for is in the class `SimpleR2dbcRepository`.  I found this by putting a break point on a call to `save` and then tracing through the AOP to find the actual class that was instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

As with many other interfaces in the Spring Data project, `CrudRepository<T,ID>` needs no implementation. Their magic works only by extending it in your own business-specific repository interface, for example:

```
public interface HistoryBooksRepository extends CrudRepository<HistoryBookEntity,Long> {   
}
```

The only thing you need to customize is the `Entity` of your choice, and its `ID` (these are the generic types). This way, when you inject your `HistoryBooksRepository` Bean in your service or controller method, you can use their CRUD methods (`save`, `saveAll`, `findById`, etc) without the need to implement any logic (given that your application is correctly wired up, of course).

You can, in addition to this, create new methods following the Spring Data naming rules, for example:

```
public interface HistoryBooksRepository extends CrudRepository<HistoryBookEntity,Long> {   

    List<HistoryBookEntity> findByPublishDateAfter(LocalDate from);

}
```

...where `publishDate` must be a valid field of your Entity. Here you can find more details regarding this powerful method for building custom queries: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, however i need to see the implementation so I can replicate it and add our custom conversion step between two entity types. One simple type containing only primitives and one consisting of entities.

Comment: @EndreMoen please then ask about your real problem, and not the secondary problem https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378

Comment: @Toerktumlare The question is clearly stated: "Where can the implementation of ReactiveCrudRepository be found?" E.g the save method sets an Id on the object. This is not stated in the method documentation. Which only states: "Saves a given entity. Use the returned instance for further operations as the save operation might have changed the entity instance completely."

Comment: but your question should be `i need to insert a custom conversion step, where is it best suited?` that is the question you should be asking. You have already decided on a solution, and now you find it hard to apply your solution. You want a solution to `Y` when your real problem is `X`